# Tricky iteration over JS object to populate table

Tags: javascript

I am really stuck here for 2 days now. I have a JS object of the form :

```
{  
  "sqlValuePair":[  
      {  
         "repLag":{  
            "host":"abc.com",
            "metric":"Replication_Lag",
            "value":{  
               "24-09-2014 13:20_0":0
            },
            "tags":"",
            "alert":"OKAY"
         },
         "slowQuery":{  
            "host":"abc.com",
            "metric":"Slow_Queries",
            "value":{  
               "24-09-2014 13:20_2":220
            },
            "tags":"",
            "alert":"ALERT"
         },
         "status":{  
            "host":"abc.com",
            "metric":"Status",
            "value":{  
               "24-09-2014 13:20_0":1
            },
            "tags":"",
            "alert":"OKAY"
         }
      },
      {  
         "repLag":{  
            "host":"abc.com",
            "metric":"Replication_Lag",
            "value":{  
               "24-09-2014 13:15_0":0
            },
            "tags":"",
            "alert":"OKAY"
         },
         "slowQuery":{  
            "host":"abc.com",
            "metric":"Slow_Queries",
            "value":{  
               "24-09-2014 13:15_0":2
            },
            "tags":"",
            "alert":"OKAY"
         },
         "status":{  
            "host":"abc.com",
            "metric":"Status",
            "value":{  
               "24-09-2014 13:15_0":1
            },
            "tags":"",
            "alert":"OKAY"
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

What I need to do is make a table which looks somewhat like this :

```
**Health    metric           date interval 1    date interval 2**
abc.com  replication Lag   OKAY               ALERT
abc.com  status            OKAY               ALERT
abc.com  Slow queries      OKAY               OKAY
def.com  replication Lag   OKAY               ALERT
def.com  status            OKAY               ALERT
def.com  Slow queries      OKAY               OKAY
```

However to fill replication Lag entries dynamically I need to iterate through the object , look for host = abc.com and then look for metric = Replication Lag and then fill that entry for that date interval.
Is there a more efficient way than :

```
var obj = JSON.parse(json.replace(/&quot;/g, '"'));
console.log("the main keys are "+Object.keys(obj));
var timeList = obj.timeList;
var sqlValuePair = obj.sqlValuePair;

for(i=0;i<timeList.length;i++){
    $("#table").append('<th>'+Object.keys(timeList[i])+'</th>');
}
for(i=0;i<Object.keys(obj).length;i++){
    var channel = Object.keys(obj)[i];
    console.log(channel); // SQL in this case
    var list = sort(sqlValuePair); // this is giving an ERROR.
    console.log(" list is "+list);
}


function comparator(Obj1, Obj2){
    if(obj1.host.localeCompare(obj.host)>=0)
        return 1;
    else return 0;
}

function sort(list){
    var temp;
    console(" entered sort ");
    console.log("the list length is "+list.length);
    for(var i=1;i<list.length;i++){
        for(var j=0;j<=i-1;j++){
            if(comparator(list[j],list[i])>0)
            {
                temp=list[i];
                list[i]=list[j];
                list[j]=temp;
            }
        }
    }
    console.log(" the sorted list is "+list);
    return list
}
```

Comment: It would be ideal if you show us some piece of code you've tried, so we can adjust it or give you another direction.

Comment: Hey, is that a bubble sort? Cool.

Comment: yeah. it is. what about it?